# PHP - cannot create array

Tags: php, arrays, syntax-error, php-5.3

I downloaded and installed Ampps and now I'm using PHP version 5.3.28. When I try to create array i.e.

```
$foo = ['bar'];
```

or

```
$foo = [];
```

or

```
$data = [
    'ts' => time(),
    'ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
    'user_id' => @$auth->id,
    'method' => $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'],
    'uri' => $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],
    'data' => json_encode([
        'get' => $_GET,
        'post' => $post,
    ]),
];
```

etc. I always got error "`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in ...`". I didn't change anything. Where is problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: `[]` array syntax requires PHP >= 5.4.0

Comment: try useing array() function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the syntax `[]` requires PHP <s>5.5.0</s>  5.4 and higher, earlier versions have to define arrays as:

```
$array = array( /* data */);
```

So, if you wish to use the syntax as exampled. then plan an upgrade to 5.5, otherwise use the alternative method to define an array -- [Array Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try something more explicit like this:

```
$dataTest = array 
     (
     "ts" => time(),
     "ip" => 7
     );

echo $dataTest["ts"];
echo $dataTest["ip"];
```